# How to use OAuth in a C# web api app when hosting multiple instances

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a C# web API application, which is using OAuth and annotations such as:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

I'm hosting it on AWS elastic beanstalk. It works fine when there is 1 instance running, but when I started to have multiple instances, I was getting unauthorised messages returned. Clearly the tokens are not valid across multiple machines.

Is there a way that I can add some configuration to the instances so that they accept tokens that have been generated on a different machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the MachineKey in web.config which can be used to share tokens between multiple machines.

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="..." validation="HMACSHA256" validationKey="..." />
```

The script to generate the machine key can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors#AppendixA).